# When are the marginals of an extremal invariant measure also extremal invariant?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-process

Let's suppose that $X$ is a compact metric space, and thus as is $X \times X$.  If given a Markov process on $X \times X$ with marginals that are Markov processes on $X$, then we know that the marginals of any stationary/invariant measure are also invariant.  Is the marginal of any probability measure that is extremal among the invariant measures for the 2-variate coupled process ("extremal" in the sense of convex analysis) also extremal among the invariant measures for the 1-variate process?

Comment: Markov processes on X×X with marginals that are Markov processes on X and not independent, are pretty rare. Do you have a specific situation in mind?

Comment: @Did There are a lot of examples of this in Tom Liggett's book on Interacting Particle systems.  For those not familiar with the setup, you describe the generator by actually describing rates of transition, say on a compact state space $\{0, 1\}^S$ where $S$ is a countable set of sites.  There is the so-called "Basic coupling" which couples two such spin systems. (markov processes on that state space arising from rates satisfying certain finiteness conditions)  This coupling has the two processes "evolving independently" when unequal, but once they are equal they lock step as much as they can.

Comment: The example I have in mind is sort of like a 4-way basic coupling, but I didn't want to ask too complicated a question and I imagine any technique used there would be generally applicable, and probably the same as anything used in any similar kind of question.  In any case, the exact development of this can be found on p. 151 of http://books.google.com/books?id=I3aNPR1FursC&q=151#v=snippet&q=151&f=false and a few pages before it.  P. 122-124 describes what I summarized above.

Comment: Right, somehow coupling was escaping me.